# How to bulk update a geom field based on lat/long?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I first tried a basic implementation through a simple for loop as below. It works but takes too long as there are 10k records.

```
panoramas = Panorama.objects.all()
for panorama in panoramas:
    panorama.geo_location = Point([panorama.longitude, panorama.latitude])
    panorama.save()
```

Based on Django's update method, I then tried something like this:

```
geo_location = Panorama.objects.all().update(
    geo_location=fromstr(f'POINT({longitude} {latitude}', srid=4326)
)
```

This does not work though as I'm trying to get Django to pick out the lat/long for each record and update geo_location based on those two fields but django doesn't know what longitude or latitude is.

Is there a way I could implement this using update()?

Answer (score 0):

Working with a value from the database in an update operation is exactly what ORM [F-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) are for.

In example from the documentation,

This:

```
reporter = Reporters.objects.get(name='Tintin')
reporter.stories_filed += 1
reporter.save()
```

Can go to this:

```
reporter = Reporters.objects.filter(name='Tintin')
reporter.update(stories_filed=F('stories_filed') + 1)
```

With the benefit of having the `stories_filed + 1` pulled and its operation (addition) ran at the database.

---

Specific example in PostGIS SQL (untested):

```
UPDATE
    panorama
SET
    geom = ST_SetSRID(
        ST_Point(panorama.longitude, panorama.latitude),
        4326
    )
FROM
    panorama
;
```

**References:** PostGIS [ST_Point](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html), PostgreSQL [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Comment: Using the F-expression throws an error though:  
**Invalid parameters given for Point initialization**    
This is what I've tried:  
`geo_location = Panorama.objects.all().update(geo_location=Point(F('longitude'), F('latitude'), srid=4326))`

Comment: @CLINTONBRAGANZA, hmm, I did not think about the point creation itself. I wonder if there is GeoDjango specific documentation for that somewhere. What I mean is, as you have it, `Point` is a GEOS Python class and the F-expressions represent some SQL that they will be replaced with at the database. Honestly, raw PostGIS SQL (or your database flavor) may be easiest since this is probably a once per dataset operation. It being ORM does not matter much here. Having the ORM model later would still be useful, after the geometry field has been created/updated. I will update my answer with some SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to bulk update the `geom` field in an optimized way. Saving each record individually in the loop was what was taking so long (as predicted), hence using django's `bulk_update()` method here is what was needed. [Django bulk_update documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

```
panoramas = Panorama.objects.all()
for panorama in panoramas:
     panorama.geo_location = Point(panorama.longitude, panorama.latitude, srid=4326)
Panorama.objects.bulk_update(panoramas, ['geo_location'])
```

Comment: It's still faster and cleaner to do it via .update and an F expression.